# Cascading Test class code coverage allowed for release in Production?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have a helper class called `LeadHelper` for the lead object and I am creating a test class called `LeadHelperTest` for it. Now the `LeadHelper` class calls other classes. After I run LeadHelperTest, the code coverager for `LeadHelper` and the classes it calls is above 75%. Now for release in Production do I need to create a separate test classes for each of those classes called by `LeadHelper`? Or is it enough just `LeadHelperTest` which calls other classes and their code coverage is also greater than 75%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you include LeadHelperTest in the change set (or whichever mechanism you're using for deployment), that is enough.